# Selecting items in a listbox with drawmode set to ownerdrawfixed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I have a listbox which I wanted some items to be a different color, and I understand to do this I have to set the drawmode to ownerdrawfixed. This works fine, but, now I can't retrieve a selected item. With the drawmode set to normal, when I click on an item in the listbox, I have it put that text into a textbox. With the drawmode set to ownerdrawfixed, when I click on an item, I get an error that "conversion from type 'item' to type 'string' is not valid. Also, the listbox is no longer sorted, even tho the sorted property is set to true (when in ownerdrawfixed mode).

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ac As Integer
        LstAll.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
        MaxRec = 708
        ChkShow = True

        FileOpen(1, "C:\MyMov3\MovData.mdt", OpenMode.Random, , , Len(Mv3Rec))
        For x = 1 To MaxRec
            FileGet(1, Mv3Rec, x + 1)

            'This If loop for the colored text
            If Mv3Rec.Rc3Mlti = True And ChkShwMlti.Checked = True Then
                ac = Asc(Trim(Mv3Rec.Rc3MTitle))
                If ac > 0 Then
                    Dim i As New Item()
                    i.ItmColor = Color.Red
                    i.Txt = Trim(Mv3Rec.Rc3MTitle)
                    LstAll.Items.Add(i)
                End If
            End If

            If ChkShow = True Then
                Dim i As New Item()             'Needed for the black text when in ownerdrawfixed mode
                i.ItmColor = Color.Black        'Needed for the black text when in ownerdrawfixed mode
                i.Txt = Trim(Mv3Rec.Rc3Title)   'Needed for the black text when in ownerdrawfixed mode
                LstAll.Items.Add(i)             'Needed for the black text when in ownerdrawfixed mode
                'LstAll.Items.Add(Trim(Mv3Rec.Rc3Title))        'This line adds the text when in normal mode
            End If
        Next
        FileClose(1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub LstAll_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles LstAll.DrawItem
        If e.Index < 0 Then Return

        Dim i As Item
        i = TryCast(LstAll.Items(e.Index), Item)

        If i IsNot Nothing Then
            e.Graphics.DrawString(i.Txt, e.Font, New SolidBrush(i.ItmColor), e.Bounds)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub LstAll_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LstAll.SelectedIndexChanged
        TextBox1.Text = LstAll.SelectedItem
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        End
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Item
    Public Txt As String
    Public ItmColor As Color
End Class
```

This code is only the essential parts.... and was tested in a new project on a blank form. With a Listbox (renamed to LstAll) A textbox, a checkbox (renamed to ChkShwMlti).  This gives the same error as in the program that I need it to work in. It does however use a file that I did not include the Structure for... but I think you can get the idea.

Comment: If you want help with code, you have to show us the code.  We are not psychics and we do not live inside your computer.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Sorry.... here is the essential code.... used in a new project to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: It won't let me paste the code now... it says it is too long

Comment: OK, I see now that by using my declared class "Item" to add the items to the listbox that I am adding that, and not the text as when in normal mode. But... how do I access the item.txt property from the listbox when I click on an item?

Comment: Please read [Ask] and take the [tour].  You have asked 4 questions and gotten 6 answers, but accepted none of them.  The [tour] explains how accepting and voting helps others find good answers.    Also, there are several good answers already here showing how to use different colors or even images for `ListControl` items.

Comment: Sorry Plutonix.... but... something seems to be wrong then, because I don't see the answers. I see your comment that I needed to post the code, my own comments where I had originally tried to do that, my comment about the "item".... and now your comment that there were 4 questions and 6 answers.   But I do not see anything else.

Comment: There are over 23,000,000 answers on SO;  I know for a certainty there are several dealing with  Ownerdraw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out this problem. In the LstAll.SelectedIndexChanged

Private Sub LstAll_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LstAll.SelectedIndexChanged

```
    Dim i As New Item
    i = LstAll.SelectedItem
    TextBox1.Text = i.Txt
```

End Sub

this worked as needed.